# How to add array of objects to apollo client mutation request?

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo-client

I am building a nativescript mobile application which consume graphql API, and I am using apollo client via apollo boost.

The problem appear when I am trying to send array of objects inside the mutation like below:

```
let {
    to,
    total,
    drugList
} = order

apolloClient.mutate({
    mutation: gql `mutation {
        makeOrder(
            to: "${to}",
            total: ${total},
            drugList: ${drugList}
        ){
            id
        }
    }`
}).then((res) => {
    console.log(res)
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
})
```

I have tried to log the drugList inside a template literals like:

```
console.log(`${drugList}`)
```

But I got **[object object],[object object]** then I have tried to use `${[...drugList]}` instead and I got the desired structure of array of objects but the mutate function of apollo client doesn't accept it (doesn't execute the mutation or log an error).

Am I miss something to make it run or are there any recommendation to run it?

Comment: What is `order`, what value exactly does `drugList` have?

Comment: Notice that in your query you are using a `gql`-tagged template literal, which you cannot compare to the simple template string in your `console.log` test.

Comment: @Bergi order object contains to, total and drugList and those are id, float and array of objects respectively.

Comment: @Bergi Okay that's a good note, but how to send an array of object inside it?

Comment: You might also try ``console.log(gql `mutation {
        makeOrder(
            to: "${to}",
            total: ${total},
            drugList: ${drugList}
        ){
            id
        }
    }`)``

Comment: @Bergi drugList are like this: 

    [{
       "drug": {
          "connect": {
           "id": "5d596dadc450450007a93467"
         }
       },
        "quantity": 2,
        "unitPrice": 22.9,
        "discount": 20,
        "total": 37}]

Comment: @Bergi trying to ````console.log(gql...)````  doesn't log anything, I think sending array of objects to gql generate an error but it doesn't log it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [**Bergi**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi), after his notice that gql-tagged template literal cannot be compared to the simple template string in a `console.log` test.

So I have searched around this and figured out that variables property would solve this problem.
Here is the final result:

```
let {
    to,
    total,
    drugList
} = order

apolloClient.mutate({
    mutation: gql `mutation ($to: ID!, $total: Float!, $drugList: [OrderDrugsListInput!]!) {
        makeOrder(
            to: $to,
            total: $total,
            drugList: $drugList
        ){
            id
        }
    }`,
    variables: {
        to: to,
        total: total,
        drugList: drugList
    }
}).then((res) => {
    console.log(res)
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
})
```